# iphone - EASY APNS,Push Notification , what should i use to run it?

Tags: iphone

im looking at http://www.easyapns.com/. Push Notifications
Im still new in iphone programming so please pardon me for any newb questions :\

i)Should i test this EASY APNS on a Mac or a Windows PC?

ii)What should i use to run this php EASY APNS so that it acts like a server.? (pardon me if im not making sense). Apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.! Needed Apache,MySql,phpAdmin. Mac or windows should be fine i think.

Answer (score 1):

Apache should do the trick; if you're new in the field of iphone programming consider looking into MAMP. Also noting, Apache comes pre-installed on all macs.